# Why can't I access directories in my home directory using the command terminal?

Tags: command-line

When I try to access directories in my home directory, I end up back at the root prompt.  Here is a link to a snapshot of what happens:

[image]

Comment: I think you have provided the wrong snapshot..please check again.

Comment: You are right.  That is the wrong snapshot.  Here is the correct one <http://i.imgur.com/sEfn6eR.png>.

Comment: Should I be able to do the following: cd /home/john/documents/...?

Comment: No. it is Documents not documents. Mind the capital D.

Comment: Newbie gets it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets break it down:

At first i am at the home directory of the logged in user (indicated by `~` sign), the name of the user is `someuser`. If you do a `pwd` you will see the full location where you currently at:

```
someuser@someuser-home:~$pwd
/home/someuser
```

Now i want to go back a directory i.e. to the `/home` directory, as you have typed:

```
someuser@someuser-home:~$ cd /home
someuser@someuser-home:/home$ pwd
/home
```

Thats right, i am currently at `/home`. Now again if i do `cd /home/someuser` i will go back to where i was previously i.e. `/home/someuser`:

```
someuser@someuser-home:/home$ cd /home/someuser
someuser@someuser-home:~$ pwd
/home/someuser
```

If you want to go some other directory that `/home/someuser` while you are at `/home` you need to `cd` into that directory (given you are permitted to do so). You can do `ls` to find the subdirectories of `/home` and then choose our desired one.

```
someuser@someuser-home:/home$ pwd
/home
someuser@someuser-home:/home$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x  4 dir           dir          4096 Jun 28  2014 dir
drwxr-xr-x  2 someuser      someuser     4096 Jan 10  2014 someuser
someuser@someuser-home:/home$ cd dir
someuser@someuser-home:/home/dir$ pwd
/home/dir
```

**EDIT:**

Now in accordance to what you have said in the comment, you want to check what is inside the directory `/home/john/documents/linux-unix`. To list a directory i.e. to check what is inside a directory you need `ls` command, not `cd`. `cd` will take you to the destination directory but `ls` will list the files or directories inside that directory. So to list a directory:

```
`ls /home/john/documents/linux-unix`
```

Now as per your Rinzwind's comments i think you are mistaking the case sensitivity of Ubuntu. Ubuntu is case sensitive i.e. `Documents` and `documents` are not same. So you can have a directory named `Documents` and a directory named `documents` at the same time in you home directory.

```
someuser@someuser-home:~$ pwd
/home/someuser
someuser@someuser-home:~$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x  2 someuser someuser    4096 Nov 22  2014 documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 someuser someuser    4096 Sep 29  2013 Documents
```

Normally `/home/someuser/Documents` is created during installation. So, as your directory `linux-unix` was inside `/home/john/Documents` you need to do:

```
cd /home/john/Documents/linux-unix
```

or to list the contents:

```
ls /home/john/Documents/linux-unix
```

Comment: I understand that.  What I don't understand is why I cannot follow a path in my home directory.  Why can't I do this, cd /home/john/documents/linux-unix and see the file in linux-unix?

Comment: You answered my question Rinzwind.

Comment: @Rinzwind: Added and explained the confusing portion.

Comment: @jdh19: Check my edits..

Comment: Appreciated it.